# Can harmonic oscillations be used to heat matter more effectively?

Tags: thermodynamics

Since heat is molecular vibrations, vibrations have frequencies, and applying energy to a system at its vibration frequency is an effective way to rapidly increased the amplitude of its vibrations, is it possible to heat matter using discrete, rapid bursts of energy at the right frequency?
Is this what Microwave ovens are doing?

Comment: Yes, in essence this is what microwave ovens are doing.

Comment: @infinitezero the operating frequency, $\approx 2.4GHz$, of a microwave oven has nothing to do with anything one might call a "molecular vibration frequency".

Comment: @hyportnex "is it possible to heat matter using discrete, rapid bursts of energy at the right frequency? Is this what Microwave ovens are doing?"

Comment: @infinitezero the microwave ovens I know about use a continuous wave (CW) and not a pulsed magnetron. The magnetron oscillates at around $2.40-2.45 GHz$ that has been the so-called ISM (industrial-scientific-manufacturing) band for a very long time. By some ancient superstition this particular spectrum allocation was believed to be related to some mythical water molecule resonance but in fact it originates in the microwave developments following WWII radar work, unrelated to anything "scientific". It is possible to heat in pulse mode but cw is just easier and simpler.